# Is it mandatory to use document.registerElement()?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

I'm using custom HTML tags such as `<custom-element>` for semantic convenience and styling those using CSS. I'm also using the tag name as a selector for jQuery such as `$('custom-element')`.

I've removed `document.registerElement('custom-element')` from my code, and everything works as expected in Chrome.

Is it mandatory to use `document.registerElement('custom-element')` even if I'm not using any Javascript with those custom elements (except for the jQuery selector)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing `registerElement` does is allow you to create objects of the new element programmatically via constructor as opposed to by using `createElement`. This enables you to also add a prototype to the element, or extend an existing element, which AFAIK you can't do with `createElement`. You don't need to register custom elements if you don't need one of these three things (a constructor, the extension of an existing element, a prototype).

Comment: Do you have any source to confirm this?

Comment: [Here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#htmlunknownelement): every unregistered custom HTML element is `HTMLUnknownElement`.